# Как узнать откуда пришёл сигнал в слоте Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Есть в трее меню, организация:

```
 // Setting system tray's icon menu...
trayIconMenu = new QMenu(this);
trayIconMenu->addAction(QPixmap(":/images/images/info.png"),"Информация", this, SLOT(openInformationDlg()));
trayIconMenu->addAction (QPixmap(":/images/images/settings.png"), "Настройки", this, SLOT(showNormal()));

p_SubMenu = new QMenu("Полезное ПО", trayIconMenu);
p_SubMenu->setIcon(QPixmap(":/images/images/monitor.png"));
trayIconMenu->addMenu(p_SubMenu);
p_SubMenu->addAction(QPixmap(":/images/images/firefox.png"), "Mozilla Firefox", this, SLOT(openUrlBrowser()));
p_SubMenu->addAction(QPixmap(":/images/images/firefox.png"), "Google Chrome", this, SLOT(openUrlBrowser()));

trayIconMenu->addAction (QPixmap(":/images/images/exit.png"), "Выход", qApp, SLOT(quit()));
```

Проблема в том что мне надо отдавать в функцию openUrlBrowser() строковый параметр, но так как сигнал принимает bool, особо это сделать не получится.
QObject::sender() тоже не помощник потому как QAction каждый раз новый (я так понимаю зависит от потока).

Comment: `sender()`'ом является `QAction`, который испускает сигнал. В чём проблема его использования? Какую строку вы хотите передавать, где её брать?

Comment: p_SubMenu->addAction(QPixmap(":/images/images/firefox.png"), "Mozilla Firefox", this, SLOT(openUrlBrowser()));
          p_SubMenu->addAction(QPixmap(":/images/images/firefox.png"), "Google Chrome", this, SLOT(openUrlBrowser()));            эти две строки, должны отсылаться в слот, но по клику они открывают две разные ссылки

Comment: Какие две строки? Вам нужны `":/images/images/firefox.png"` и `"Mozilla Firefox"` внутри `openUrlBrowser()`? Пожалуйста, сформулируйте вопрос конкретно, что есть и что нужно, иначе дать ответ на Ваш вопрос не представляется возможным.

Comment: OpenUrlBrowser() - должен передаваться параметр с ссылкой QUrl, но только когда параметр там присутствует, приложение ругается что слот отсутствует, из-за несовпадении параметров между сигналом и слотом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, я так и не понял, что же всё таки нужно, но попробую поиграть с хрустальным шаром. Допустим у нас есть слот `openUrlBrowser`, в котором нам нужно выполнить следующие действия:

1. Понять какой браузер открывать
2. Открыть нужную ссылку.

Хорошо, итого нам надо поставить 2 куска данных в `openUrlBrowser`, который может принимать, в лучшем случае, только `bool`.
Раз не можем передать данные, значит пойдём другим путём, создадим в нашем классе QMap:
`QMap<void*, QPair<QUrl, QString>> m_Map;`. Теперь, когда мы добавляем новый `QAction` в меню, мы пихаем его и в наш `QMap`:

```
void* action = trayIconMenu->addAction(...);
m_Map.insert(action, qMakePair(QUrl(someUrl), "Chrome"));
```

Теперь идём в реализацию слота `openUrlBrowser`:

```
void openUrlBrowser()
{
    ...
    QPair parameters = m_Map[sender()];
    if(parameters.second == "Chrome")
       openInChrome(parameters.first);
    ...
}
```

Разумеется код выше не тестировался и может иметь опечатки, описки. Я просто хотел показать идею.

Comment: Мне надо открывать ссылку... а не определённый браузер... а ссылка уже открывается браузером по умолчанию

Comment: @LevBazdyrev, ну Вы же можете адаптировать мой ответ под свои нужды, или нет?

Comment: В принципе да, могу, при чём пошурстил доку нашёл QSignalMapper, там довольно интересные реализации... Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @LevBazdyrev, да, QSignalMapper довольно интересно выглядит — никогда им не пользовался.

Comment: @LevBazdyrev, если используете C++11, то можете воспользоваться лямбда-функцией в качестве слота - очень облегчает работу в такого рода случаях.

Comment: @ixSci Ну вот есть повод попробовать.

Comment: @PavelParshin слышал за лямбда функцию но никогда не пробовал, нодо будет познакомится